# to save to the server, correct the invalid or missing required properties

Tags: sharepoint-server, word, properties

We are using SP 2013 and Office 2010 (yes old) and we are having some trouble when saving a new document to the library as the required fields, even though they are filled in, are still considered as empty.

In the print screen below, requestor is a people and group field. When I enter a user's name I can't confirm him/her and the border still remains red dotted.

Any solution to this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Please narrow down your issue as following:

1. When you edit the existing document properties, whether the required property still remains as required?
2. Leave the required property empty, and try to edit the document properties in the library UI after saving the document to library, check if you can add the required column.
3. Check whether this issue exists in other libraries.
4. Besides, you can [repair the Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and check again:

Comment: when editing the component I believe is just fine, or event when you upload the document and then update the properties. The issue exists only when the user clicks on "New" button in the library.